# Angular: Passing data binding as argument is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So far, this approach works:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let it of item | itemFilter:'AnyString'">
```

However, with data binding it does not work as follows:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let it of item | filter:{{filterstr}}">
<div class="container" *ngFor="let it of item | filter:'{{filterstr}}'">
<div class="container" *ngFor="let it of item | filter:{{filterSearch.toString()}}">
```

My pipe function is as follows:

import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core'

```
@Pipe({name:'filter'})
export class ItemsPipe implements PipeTransform
{  
    transform(items:Array<any>, filterString:String):any{

            return items.filter(item=>{

                if(item.name.includes(filterString))
                    return item

            })
    }
}
```

My component module:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  filterstr: String;
  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.filterstr = 'anything';

  }
}
```

I thought I was accidentally passing null in the parameter, yet even after I initialize 'filterSearch', it doesn't work.

Additionally, I would have to filter the array list by keys as well. What parameter type should I set for the transform function?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Remove the projection, this `*ngFor="let it of item | filter:filterstr"` should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: @dcg Wow..., hours and hours wasted. Thank you very much. If I want to filter by keys in an array, what parameter type should I set in pipe function, any clue??

Comment: Did you solved this? I have same requirement. If you have correct answer, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let it of item | filter:filterstr">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**template.html**

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let it of item | filter:filterstr">
```

**pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({name:'filter'})
export class ItemsPipe implements PipeTransform
{  
    transform(items:Array<any>, filterString:String):any{

            if(filter === '') {
              return items;
            } else {
               return items.filter(item=>{ if(item.name.includes(filterString))
                    return item
               })
            }
    }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
filterstr: String = '';
```

Initially your search input will empty so pipe will return all items.
As soon as you start typing in input pipe will return filtered items;